# Determine basis and dimension of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^{4}$, such that
$$U = \{(a + 2b, a, a - 3b, 3a + 5b) | a,b \in \mathbb R\}$$
how should I go about determining the basis or the dimension of this subspace?

I've been googling and trying stuff out, but I'm not sure what I'm doing.
When I took

$$\begin{align*}x &= a + 2b\\
y &= a\\
z &= a - 3b\\
t &= 3a + 5b\end{align*}$$

and tried to solve that as a system of equations, I didn't get anything useful.
I seem to get that $b=\frac{x-y}{2}=\frac{x-z}{5}=3x-t$.

Solving for $a$ in the same way gives me $a=y=2t-5x=\frac{3x+2z}{5}$, but I'm unsure as to what to do with this information.

I'm not sure if I'm doing anything properly.
I'd appreciate any clues on what I'm working with here! Sorry if this question is kinda weird.

Also, it's my first time posting a question here, so any kind of feedback regarding how I wrote/formatted it is more than welcome!

Comment: Nice Mathjax for a first time user! Made some edits to improve the appearance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(a + 2b, a, a - 3b, 3a + 5b)=a(1,1,1,3)+b(2,0,-3,5)$, hence $U=\text{span}\{(1,1,1,3),(2,0,-3,5)\}$. Can you check that these two vectors are linearly independent and indeed form a basis of $U$?

Comment: Oh, is that really all there's to it? So, the dimension of the subspace $V$ is 2, correct?

Comment: @Cybex Yes, that is correct.